# redirection to other page with encoded url

Tags: c#, html

I am using one Image on my html page. where i am adding one anchor to that image to give the link. 
that anchor contains href as **~/LB/lct.aspx?pid=177&cat=Happily In Love**

Main Thing This URL IS COMING FROM DATABASE. Manually i am not entering it..

So its a Invalid URL Because of spaces between **Happily In Love**

I used Httputility.urlencoding and decoding also........but the problem i am facing is that..

Url is endoded properly but while i am clicking on the image its not redirecting to proper page because encoded url is not decoded..

How to resolve this...pls help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code

```
    string url = "~/LB/lct.aspx?pid=177&cat=Happily In Love"; //your input
    string[] arr = url.Split('?');
    var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(arr[1]);
    foreach (var n in nameValues.AllKeys)
    {
        nameValues.Set(n, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nameValues[n]));
    }
    url = arr[0] + "?" + nameValues.ToString(); //your output
```

> Use the following code to decode Querystring values

```
string cat = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["cat"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, but if it's just the spaces that are causing problems, consider replacing them with a `+` using a string replace:

```
string newurl = url.Replace(" ","+");
```

Note that this is only really safe if the spaces are restricted to the contents of a querystring.